# Heatmap.py IndexError on CSV input

Tags: python, heatmap, gnuradio

************Update Below!***************

I have several CSVs for which I'm trying to generate Heatmap Images for analysis but I am unable to generate an image.  I've checked CSVs for blank lines and I've tried different files.

```
user@host:~/Downloads/sdr-misc/rtl-sdr-misc/heatmap$ ./heatmap.py ~/Documents/StoGB1.csv image.jpg
    loading
    x: 7260, y: 1822, z: (-136.700000, -11.050000)
    drawing
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./heatmap.py", line 618, in <module>
        img = push_pixels(args)
      File "./heatmap.py", line 420, in push_pixels
        pix[x,y+tape_height+1] = rgb(zs[x])
      File "./heatmap.py", line 360, in rgb_inner
        return palette[tone_scaled]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Line 618 is:

```
print("drawing")
img = push_pixels(args)
```

Line 420:

```
    for x in range(len(zs)):
        pix[x,y+tape_height+1] = rgb(zs[x])
```

Line 360:

```
tone_scaled = int(tone * (len(palette)-1))
return palette[tone_scaled]
```

************Update*******************

The problem is actually coming from very low points in the sweep data.

I have negative spikes or pits that jump from -60 to -90dB, and then it drops to -136 or -145.

These pits are what is causing an IndexError.

Mossman's Heatmap.py is trying to push_pixels but rgb_inner where the IndexError occurs on large negative spikes.  Is it division by zero or something?  The large negative value breaks the array index math computation perhaps but this is my first dive into Python and I'm slow any help is appreciated!

line 621

img = push_pixels(args)

File "./heatmap.py", line 422, in push_pixels

pix[x,y+tape_height] = rgb(zs[x])

File "./heatmap.py", line 362, in rgb_inner

return palette[tone_scaled]

rgb_inner is defined:

```
def rgb_fn(palette, min_z, max_z):

    "palette is a list of tuples, returns a function of z"

    def rgb_inner(z):

        tone = (z - min_z) / (max_z - min_z)

        tone_scaled = int(tone * (len(palette)-1))

        return palette[tone_scaled]

    return rgb_inner
```

rgb_inner is being called by rgb_fn by the function push_pixels:

```
def push_pixels(args):

    "returns PIL img"

    width = len(args.freqs)

    rgb = rgb_fn(args.palette(), args.db_limit[0], args.db_limit[1])

    img = Image.new("RGB", (width, tape_height + args.pix_height))

    pix = img.load()

    x_size = img.size[0]

    average = [0.0] * width

    tally = 0

    old_y = None

    height = len(args.times)

    for t, zs in collate_row(x_size):

        y = args.times.index(t)

        if not args.compress:

            for x in range(len(zs)):

                pix[x,y+tape_height] = rgb(zs[x])

            continue

        # ugh

        y = args.pix_height - time_compression(height - y, args.compress)

        if old_y is None:

            old_y = y

        if old_y != y:

            for x in range(len(average)):

                pix[x,old_y+tape_height] = rgb(average[x]/tally)

            tally = 0

            average = [0.0] * width

        old_y = y

        for x in range(len(zs)):

            average[x] += zs[x]

        tally += 1

    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a lower minimum point using the `--db` argument, like so:

Since " then it drops to -136 or -145", run:

```
./heatmap.py --db -150 0 data.csv image.jpg
```

that will make sure it renders anything not below -150 too.